# Check for guest rootkits from the KVM host system?

Tags: linux-kernel, kvm

Since a compromised virtual machine cannot be trusted for rootkit detection would it be theoretically possible to try to detect rootkits from the host system?
Maybe even something like checking runtime kernel integrity through periodic snapshots or something?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Found this paper:
https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~adunn/pubs/osck.pdf

Don't know why it's not part of KVM yet...